# How to get values in [object Object] in to an Array or how can i access those values in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

This is my Angular Code which i have written in component.ts file.I am getting data from backend API and try to `console.log` and see the data.

```
getInfo() {
    const params = [];
       
    params.push({code: 'Code', name: 'ty_PSD'});
    params.push({code: 'continentCodes', name: ['CAN']});
    params.push({code: 'dateFrom', name: '2019-01-01'});
    params.push({code: 'dateTo', name: '2019-12-31'});
    params.push({code: 'statusType', name: 'REAL'});
    params.push({code: 'valueType', name: 'TTV'});
        this.serviceHandler.getDemand([], params).subscribe(
          demand => {       
            console.log(demand + 'ddd');
    
          });
      }
```

But in here `console.log(demand + 'ddd');` api response is [image]shown like this.

This is my `console.log(demand)` output.[image]
How could i get values in data: Array(365) values in to an array.

Comment: console.log(demand) and show the output

Comment: You can also log multiple "things" - `console.log(demand, 'ddd')`

Comment: console.log output is like  [object Object]ddd.

Comment: It is at the moment because your're concatenating the response object with a string. The serialization of an object is `[object Object]`. If you follow mine or Adrita's advice you will see the object itself.

Comment: ddd means that I have concat it with a string

Comment: Yes, that's your problem...

Comment: Try *not* concatenating it with a string

Comment: @ Adrita Sharma console.log(demand) it shows the output

Comment: @Kurt Hamilton i have added  console.log(demand) output.And i want to get only data: Array(365) in to an array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212244/discussion-between-hansani-and-kurt-hamilton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not concatenate/sum an object with a string because `console.log` parses the object as a string.

I think you want the number 4 in the examples bellow: `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj) + 'aaa');`

```js
var obj = { a: 'aa', b: 0, c: true};

console.log(1, obj + 'aaa');
console.log(2, obj);
console.log(3, JSON.stringify(obj));
console.log(4, JSON.stringify(obj) + 'aaa');
```

Answer (score 0):

The API response is in string format. You need to parse it.

Try:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(demand))
```